# Column ALIAS not recognized in HAVING clause, unkown column error

Tags: mysql, sql, having-clause

```
SELECT u.*, zz.contid, zz.lng, zz.lat, zz.zip, zz.city, zz.state, (**calc distance**) AS distance
FROM contacts zz
INNER JOIN users u
ON zz.id = u.id
WHERE cond1 = 1, cond2=2, etc..
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING MIN(distance) < 100
```

**Error:** unknown column distance

Any idea why this is? and how to fix it?

I appreciate any advice, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Since `MIN()` is an aggregate function, its argument must be a column value, not an alias.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with PHP or sessions. Please correct the tags.

Comment: I added the `sql` tag. It would be helpful if you also added the specific DBMS you're using.

Comment: Sorry about the tags, I corrected that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What database is this? If it's something like MSSQL, you can't use aliases like that elsewhere in a query. You'll have to replicate the whole alias definition:

```
SELECT big+ugly+calculation AS foo
...
HAVING (big+ugly_calculation) = bar
```

Or wrap the query in another:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT *, big+ugly+calculation AS foo )
WHERE foo = bar
```

Comment: The difference between `HAVING` versus `WHERE` is that `HAVING` *can* refer to aliases. However, it can't refer to an aggregate of an alias.

Comment: But that's the point of HAVING, to check aggregates.  Otherwise it would be in your where clause.

Comment: I tried using distance in where clause and removing having, still getting unknown column error

Comment: Did you read my first line? You can't use aliases like that elsewhere in the same query. changing it from 'having' to 'where' won't change the fact that you're trying to use an alias within the same query.

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to an alias in an aggregate function. Move the query into a subquery, and then aggregate it in the outer query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT u.*, zz.contid, zz.lng, zz.lat, zz.zip, zz.city, zz.state, (**calc distance**) AS distance
    FROM contacts zz
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON zz.id = u.id
    WHERE cond1 = 1, cond2=2, etc..) subquery
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(distance) < 100
```